# Spring JPA transaction is commited but no record in db

Tags: spring, jpa, asynchronous, runnable, transactional

I have a problem with transactions when I try to committ it in separate thread. Here is the code :

```
UserPhoneService.java
@Transactional
private void initializeAndSavePhoneNumberForUser(...){
....
userPhoneNumberRepository.save(phoneNumber);
        afterCommitExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.error("After commin");
                final String changeset = ChangesetFactory.createEmailChangeset(ChangesetFactory.ACTION_CREATE,
                        phoneNumber);
                changesetRevisionService.add(saaspassUser.getSaaspassId(), changeset, ChangesetCategoryEnum.PHONE);
            }
        });
```

After transaction committed the program invokes add method from ChangeSetRevisionService . Here is that code

```
@Transactional
    public Integer add(final String saaspassUserId, final String changeset, final ChangesetCategoryEnum category) {


        System.out.println("Class name : " + this.getClass().getName());
        Integer latestRevision = 0;

        try {
            final SaaspassUser saaspassUser = saaspassUserRepository.findBySaaspassId(saaspassUserId);
            latestRevision = revisionRepository.findLatestRevision(saaspassUser.getId());
            if (latestRevision == null) {
                latestRevision = 0;
            }
            final Revision revision = new Revision();
            revision.setSaaspassUser(saaspassUser);
            revision.setChangeset(changeset);
            revision.setCategory(category);
            revision.setRevisionNumber(++latestRevision);
            log.debug("Going to insert new changeset [{}]", revision);
            final Revision save = revisionRepository.save(revision);      

            log.debug("New changeset inserted [{}]", revision, save);
        } finally {
            locks.unlock(saaspassUserId);
        }
        return latestRevision;
    }
```

The problem is - 
**final Revision save = revisionRepository.save(revision)**;
Save method is executed but no record in db.
Any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: How are you calling `initializeAndSavePhoneNumberForUser`? Since it is a private method, `@Transactional` doesn't do anything, because only (public) methods called through a Spring proxy are enhanced with annotated behavior.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the comment.Yes you are right about private methods and @Transactional bahavior.But here  that is not issue.I removed Transactional from the initializeAndSavePhoneNumberForUser() method and I called changesetRevisionService.add() synchronous.In that case I got record in db.If I move changeSetRevisionService.add again in run part no record in db.After that i add @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) to add method,and I got new record in revision table.I read that requires_new open new transaction.What is background behavior here?Is this correct way...